# Can this be accomplished without a subset?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g

I have a table structure that looks like this:

Columns:
Account Number
Service Code
Quantity

Accounts can have multiple service codes on separate rows.  For example, for this account '1868603', their service codes are stored like this:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  SERVICE_CODE    SERVICE_QUANTITY
1868603     101     1
1868603     101     1
1868603     101     1
1868603     101     1
1868603     101     1
1868603     101     1
1868603     326     1
1868603     326     1
1868603     327     1
1868603     327     1
1868603     328     1
1868603     328     1
```

I am writing a query which need to see if specific service codes are on their account.  I am not concerned about the quantity.  I just want to see if they exist for an account.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, COUNT(SERVICE_CODE) HOW_MANY
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SERVICE_CODE 
    FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICES
    WHERE   ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 1868603 
        AND     SERVICE_CODE IN('323','326','327','328')
)
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

Which gives me:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  HOW_MANY
1868603 3
```

3 is the correct number, because there are three instances of IN('323','326','327','328'), which is what I'm trying to determine.

Is there a way to simplify this query without subsetting the data first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can ORACLE do `COUNT(DISTINCT <field>)`?

```
SELECT
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER, COUNT(DISTINCT SERVICE_CODE) HOW_MANY
FROM
  CUSTOMER_SERVICES
WHERE
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 1868603 
  AND SERVICE_CODE IN('323','326','327','328')
GROUP BY
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

Also, note that having sub-querys does not *always* imply poor performance.  SQL is a language for expressing the logic, but it is compiled and executed in a way you may not feel resembles the SQL very closely.

As such windowing functions (like DENSE_RANK) may also have different performance charactertics worthy of a try...

```
SELECT
  account_number,
  MAX(rank_id)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    account_number,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY account_number ORDER BY service_code) AS rank_id
  FROM
    customer_services
  WHERE
    account_number = 1868603 
    AND service_code IN('323','326','327','328')
)
  AS Data
GROUP BY
  account_number
```

Comment: Yes, Oracle can http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm. Are you asking or answering?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, COUNT(DISTINCT SERVICE_CODE) HOW_MANY
FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICES
WHERE   ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 1868603 
AND     SERVICE_CODE IN('323','326','327','328')
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```